# AC/DC power supply: help to choose fuse, varistor and/or TVS diode

Tags: fuses, ac-dc, tvs, varistor

I'm going to use this [12VDC AC/DC power supply](https://docs-emea.rs-online.com/webdocs/15e9/0900766b815e9b56.pdf) . It is the first time that I am going to use one and I have some questions about over voltage protection and peak current protection. These are the questions:

1. The AC / DC internally has a 1A slow blow fuse. Is it necessary to add an external fuse? Maybe something less than 1A to protect the internal fuse?
2. Regarding the input overvoltage protection, I have thought to use a varactor. The problem is that I do not know to find the information in the datasheet about the maximum input AC voltage. What characteristics should the varactor have: max. continuous voltage, max. clamping voltage and energy rating? I have found this good explanation ([How to choose the right Metal Oxide Varistor (MOV)](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/359149/how-to-choose-the-right-metal-oxide-varistor-mov)) but I still do not know how to choose the varactor because I can not find all the information in the AC / DC converter datasheet.
3. About the output overvoltage protection, I have read this parameter in the datasheet: '*Over Voltage Protection (OVP)' -> '125% - 195%, auto recovery*'. I do not understand this parameter well. Should I add a TVS diode to guarantee never to exceed 195% of 12VDC?

Below is a circuit diagram to clarify:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fpjGaK.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it necessary to add an external fuse? Maybe something less than 1A
>   to protect the internal fuse?

If the internal fuse blows then it's very likely that it's because the unit has developed a permanent fault. The fuse is present (as it is on most SMPSs) for regulatory reasons.

The input voltage range is rated at 85-264 volts and it will be fine even if this is overloaded by 10 % usually. They also say on their data sheet that there is a CB Report and maybe you could get hold of this just to double check on things. I wouldn't be considering using anything external on the AC side.

> 'Over Voltage Protection (OVP)' -> '125% - 195%, auto recovery'. I do
>   not understand this parameter well.

This again is likely to be another regulatory feature to prevent unsafe (to humans) output voltages. Normally this type of protection is implemented internally using a crow-bar circuit.

If you can't live with the output rising to potentially 195% of nominal then I'd consider a TVS diode.